# Initializing a 2D array for enquiries

Tags: python, algorithm, list, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array. I have to initialize the array by marking the number of 1's in the rectangle from the top left point to all points.

Original 2D array:

```
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

1st step (sum vertical elements with the previous one):

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

2nd step (sum horizontal elements with the previous one):

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
[1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 4, 5, 5, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 4, 5, 5, 7, 8, 10]
```

Both of these operations are O(n<sup>2</sup>). Is there a quicker way to initialize the list?

Comment: You want to make a list of size n^2, you are not going to have less complexity than O(n^2) to fill it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot avoid quadratic time, but there is no need in two steps
(OK, code with correct answer looks longer a bit :))

```
lst=[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
lst.append([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1])
lst.append([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0])
lst.append([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
for i in range(1.len(lst)):
    for j in range(len(lst[0])):
        if (i>0):
            lst[i][j] += lst[i-1][j]
        if (j>0):
            lst[i][j] += lst[i][j-1]
        if (i>0) & (j>0):
            lst[i][j] -= lst[i-1][j-1]

print(lst)

>>>[[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2], 
    [1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6], 
    [1, 4, 5, 5, 7, 8, 9], 
    [1, 4, 5, 5, 7, 8, 10]]
```

or without if's:

```
for j in range(1,len(lst[0])):
    lst[0][j] += lst[0][j-1]
for i in range(1,len(lst)):
    lst[i][0] += lst[i-1][0]
for i in range(1,len(lst)):
     for j in range(1,len(lst[0])):
        lst[i][j] = lst[i][j] + lst[i-1][j] + lst[i][j-1] - lst[i-1][j-1]
```

Comment: @martineau Is such using of `if` valid?

Comment: @Kurns I missed subtraction part. Added.